# multiple sql queries on single php page

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have this code

```
 <?php
include("db.php");
$sql="select * from lead";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$i=0;
 ?>
 <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
if($row['del']==1){ 
$sql1="select count(*) from notes where lead_id='$row[lead_id]'";
$var=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
                $var=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
                $var1=mysqli_num_rows($var);
?>
```

and below this php code is table which displays the data fetched by $row.The problem is I am not getting the correct count of rows.It shows 1 but I have multiple rows with same lead id

Comment: Nobody will stop you to use even 100 of them. Just make sure you do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call for `$sql1="select count(*) from notes where lead_id='$row[lead_id]'";` 
and you have 
`$var=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
 $var1=mysqli_num_rows($var);`

But that mysql_query will return only one row with `count(*)`.

 So you have to do 
`$sql1="select * from notes where lead_id='$row[lead_id]'";` 
and call 
`mysqli_num_rows($var);`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$var=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
```

to

```
$var = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql1);
```

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean. It gives this error